# (#371) Some subcategories don't represent a place

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting this error when sending some `place_topics` on an update request to the Facebook Graph API for a given Facebook Location Page.

`{"error"=>{"message"=>"(#371) Some subcategories don't represent a place.", "type"=>"OAuthException", "code"=>371, "error_subcode"=>1721087, "fbtrace_id"=>"CIewiBZL+jf"}}`

It is fixed by changing the `category_id` for another one. BTW, I would like to know if is there a way of knowing which categories are allowed and which ones doesn't. It would be nice to know it in advance to disallow some of the Facebook Categories in the editing process of our tool and avoid errors.

Thanks,

David.

Answer (score 0):

Use `search?type=placetopic&topic_filter=all` in graph explorer to get list of valid place topics